# Path already exists ERROR using DatastoreExportOperator on Airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to load some datastore files into GCS using the DatastoreExportOperator  operator.
The config is the following:

```
export_collection = DatastoreExportOperator(
    task_id='export_data_to_gcs',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET,
    datastore_conn_id='google_cloud_datastore_default',
    cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',   
    overwrite_existing=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

however, even after setting up the `overwrite_existing=True,` parameter, I am still receiving the Path already exists error.

Answer (score 0):

According to code in [github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/datastore.py) it seems like the condition should need "namespace" to be filled. You can see in the code (line 116) that if overwrite_existing and namespace then first the files in namespace are deleted.